# Creating a list of text message threads Android

Tags: android

I'm creating a basic text messaging UI for Android. I'm using an `ArrayList<String>` adapter to store the different numbers I have sent a message to. Each item in this list view opens a new view that has all the sent messages to that number.

The problem is I can only figure out how to do this using a static variable for the message. Therefore every time I send a message it updates it in every one of the conversations. Is there anyway I can get it to update the messages individually for each different number?

Comment: use asynchronous method for update array list or thread safe list.

Comment: What do you mean by that. If im making them non static i have to actually create instances of that object, but how do i have it create a new instance everytime i send a message

Comment: use angular js factory and service?